# Node throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning for Mongoose requests using Promise.all with .catch() statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to Node/Mongoose and am trying to handle errors correctly in a script to add players to a league. In the below code, explicitly thrown and non-Promise related errors are caught correctly by the .catch() statement, but rejected Promises are not.

For example, trying to pass an invalid userID throws `User not found`.

But if I test Promise rejection by disconnecting the database, I get the following:

```
(node:6252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Am I using Promise.all() and .catch() incorrectly somehow?

Just to be clear, I'm trying to work out why the error isn't being handled, not why the error is being thrown.

My script:

```
const 
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = require('./models/users'),
League = require('./models/leagues'),
dbUrl = process.env.DBURL || 'mongodb://localhost/predictor';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const addUserToLeague = (userId, leagueId) => {
    let foundUser = User.findById(userId);
    let foundLeague = League.findById(leagueId);

    return Promise.all([foundUser, foundLeague])
    .then(arr => {
        if(!arr[0]){
            throw 'User not found';
        }else if(!arr[1]){
            throw 'League not found';
        }
        return arr;
    })
    .then(arr => {
        arr[0].leagueMemberships.push(arr[1]);
        arr[1].users.push(arr[0]);
        return arr;
    })
    .then(updatedArr => {
        updatedArr[0].save();
        updatedArr[1].save();
        return updatedArr;
    })
    .then(updatedArr => { console.log(`User ${updatedArr[0]._id} added to league ${updatedArr[1]._id}`) })
    .catch(err => { console.log('Error:', err) });
};

addUserToLeague(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]); // Needs 2 args: User ID and League ID
```

Comment: Given the error message is `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server`, it sounds like `mongoose.connect(…)` returns a promise that is getting rejected.

Comment: `mongoose.connect()` is not part of the promise chain in the example code. No catch block applies to it so when connection fails, you get this error.

Comment: ^^ The actual use of `Promise.all` is okay, although one hopes that `findById` doesn't *resolve* the promise with a falsy value if the item isn't found, so that whole first `then` handler seems unnecessary. The actions in the second `then` handler would be better handled directly on the `findById` promises. Also: Does `save` return a promise? If so, you're not handling rejection from it.

Comment: Here's a nice explanation: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/493#issuecomment-73977641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bergi pointed out, the error would appear to be from `connect`, which [returns a promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect) that you're not handling at all — including not waiting for it to finish. So at a minimum, you need to handle that:

```
const connectionPromise = mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle connection error
    });
```

Then in `addUserToLeague`:

```
const addUserToLeague = (userId, leagueId) => {
    return connectionPromise.then(connection => {
        // ...logic here
    });
};
```

...**but**, I question whether you should be connecting when the module is loaded like that, rather than passing a connection into `addUserToLeague`.

---

Aside from that, the actual use of `Promise.all` is okay, but:

1. One hopes that `findById` doesn't *resolve* the promise with a falsy value if the item isn't found, so that whole first `then` handler seems unnecessary.
2. Presumably `save`  returns a promise. You're not handling rejection or waiting for resolution of those if so.
3. I'd use destructuring to avoid `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, as it's easy to forget the order.
4. There's no reason for the `then` handler with the `push` calls to be separate from the `then` handler doing the saving.
5. `addUserToLeague` should return the result of the promise chain, so that code calling it A) Knows when it's finished, and B) Knows when it fails.
6. Errors shouldn't be handled in `addUserToLeague`; instead, handle them in its caller.
7. There's also the issue that the data is [*denormalized*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): You're storing the membership information in both the user object and the league object. Maybe that's relatively normal in document databases (I wouldn't know); in an RDBMS you'd store the information in a *single* place. The reason is clear from the code in `addUserToLeague`: What if saving the user succeeds but saving the league fails? Then the user object says it's a member of a league the league object doesn't say it's a member of. There's also the problem that since it's stored in two places, even if nothing goes wrong, for a brief period one of the (the user or the league) will have been saved but the other won't have been. Both are integrity problems. If you can normalize it to storing this information in one place, that would be good. If you can't, you need to update the code so that it saves one of them, waits for that to succeed, saves the other, and if that fails attempts to undo the change to the first.

Something like this (I don't attempt to address the normalization issue here, that's a big picture thing):

```
const 
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = require('./models/users'),
League = require('./models/leagues'),
dbUrl = process.env.DBURL || 'mongodb://localhost/predictor';

const addUserToLeague = (connection, userId, leagueId) => {
    return Promise.all([
        User.findById(userId),
        League.findById(leagueId)
    ])
    .then(([user, league]) => {
        user.leagueMemberships.push(league);
        league.users.push(user);
        return Promise.all([user.save(), league.save()]);
    })
    .then((([user, league]) => {
        console.log(`User ${user._id} added to league ${league._id}`);
    });
};

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(connection => addUserToLeague(connection, process.argv[2], process.argv[3]) // Needs 2 args: User ID and League ID
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

If you're using any recent verson of Node, you can use an `async` function:

```
const 
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = require('./models/users'),
League = require('./models/leagues'),
dbUrl = process.env.DBURL || 'mongodb://localhost/predictor';

const addUserToLeague = async (connection, userId, leagueId) => {
    let [user, league] = await Promise.all([
        User.findById(userId),
        League.findById(leagueId)
    ]);
    user.leagueMemberships.push(league);
    league.users.push(user);
    [user, league] = await Promise.all([user.save(), league.save()]);
    console.log(`User ${user._id} added to league ${league._id}`);
};

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(connection => addUserToLeague(connection, process.argv[2], process.argv[3]) // Needs 2 args: User ID and League ID
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer, all makes complete sense. Just one follow up - I haven't seen arguments passed in this way before:
`.then(([user, league]) => {...`
I've not seen this format before. Is this a regular ES5 way of passing 2 arguments into a function as an array, or some ES6 format? I've used destructuring but not seen it this way before.

Comment: @abr - It's parameter destructuring (ES2015+). It's just like destructuring assignment, but with parameters. So ``function x([a, b]) { console.log(`a = ${a}, b = ${b}`); } const a = [1, 2]; x(a);`` outputs `a = 1, b = 2`. You can do all the things you can do with destructuring assignment, including destructuring objects as well as arrays, providing default values for destructured elements, etc.